# Qt can't include *.h from static lib into my prog

Tags: c++, qt, include, static-libraries, .a

I'm a bit of a newbie at Qt and i can't find why my .h from my lib won't be included.

the error message is :

> error: setting.h: No such file or directory

the lib was build without trouble.

i added it with Qtcreator by right cliking on my program project ->  add library -> External library -> browse for my library file and path on my computer and added the libToolSettin.a.

This produced this code to add it into the .pro file:

> unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Tools/build-libToolSetting-Desktop-Debug/ -llibToolSetting
>
> INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Tools/build-libToolSetting-Desktop-Debug
> DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Tools/build-libToolSetting-Desktop-Debug
>
> win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../Tools/build-libToolSetting-Desktop->Debug/libToolSetting.lib
> else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../Tools/build-libToolSetting-Desktop-Debug/liblibToolSetting.a

i'm a at loss as to why it won't work so thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: already verified it's the right path. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries have *binaries* and *headers*. Headers are not automagically available just because you linked in the binary library files. You have to ensure that they are on the inclusion path in your compiler settings.

Comment: can't verified until tomorrow but i think it must be the right solution.